# IntelliJ unable to connect to SonarQube Server running in Docker

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, sonarqube

I'm trying to connect to a SonarQube server running on my machine in a Docker.
I installed the SonarLint plugin in IntelliJ, when I create the new connection to the server, given the token to the plugin, it shows:

> Failed to connect the server. Please check the configuration. Error:
>   Fail to request http://localhost:9000/api/system/status

this URL works in the browser, giving back

```
{"id":"BF41A1F2-AWlcxJRKJ9-nWLU3WeGl","version":"7.6.0.21501","status":"UP"}
```

in the SonarLint log it says:

> Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line:

I just pulled the last sonarqube image from docker repository and run it with only the port forwarding option (-p 9000:9000)

My environment:

- SonarQube server version: 7.6.0.21501 ;
- Java: 1.8.0_181
- Docker: 2.0.0.3 (31259)
- IntelliJ: Community 18.3.5

Comment: after this Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: there are five squares , they are showed in the question preview but I can't see them in the posted question

Comment: please post the error message in a comment so i can update your question with it.

Comment: Do you use any kind of proxy, firewall, antivirus?

Comment: @Kootli i'm using Avast due to internal policy

Comment: @MostafaHussein it seems that the squares are not appearing neither in the comments

Comment: ok guys so thanking a friend I found a workaround. I used the pc name instead of localhost and it worked... can't tell why... I leave the question open for someone that can resolve the localhoste issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround.
use the machine name instead localhost.